# Is there a way to show a loading spinner in react-virtualized table while data is being fetched or reloaded?

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I am new to use "react-virtualized" table. Till now experience is very good with it. I could not figure out how to show a loading spinner inside table while data is being fetched or data is being reloaded based on some external parameter.

Comment: you can make your own overlay with the same width/height as the table and use absolute positioning to put it over the table and show your spinner there

Comment: Yes I am aware of that but I was looking for any option that is provided by `react-virtualized` like there is provision to mention `no-data-row` when there is no data present in the table.

Comment: I tried using react-loading-overlay, but it seems to interfere with the table rendering.  Would love to hear if anyone has dealt with this.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to answer this, but I think you could try using `InfiniteLoader`, it did solve the issue for me, you can find a great example of its usage [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/in64f?file=/src/App.js:1055-1449).
This will work for when data is being loaded into the table, but I don't think it'll work for a fetch call, for that I'd recommend a more homemade approach such as creating an overlay with the spinner and render it conditionally.